# Pear/Mail Send array in body.

Tags: php, arrays, forms, email, post

I have two problems, When I use the [PEAR/Mail](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php) to send a form to my email, the email is received but it only allows me to send 3 variables. That said, I'm trying to send an array of value, but my script only prints the word "Array" on the message body. Here is my code:

```
     require_once "Mail.php";

     $from = $_POST['email'];
     $to = "xxxxxxxx";
     $subject = $_POST['Evento'];
     $name = $_POST['Nombre'];
     $body = $_POST['mensaje']; 

     $host = "xxxxxxx";
     $username = "xxxxxxx";
     $password = "xxxxxxx";

     $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);




     $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $name, $body);
```

This code connects and sends the email fine, but only displays up to the third variable (`$name`) if I switch the display to `$body`. So I thought, lets make an array and send all the message in one variable. So I made this:

```
    require_once "Mail.php";
  $from = $_POST['email'];
  $to = "xxxxxxx";
  $subject = $_POST['Evento'];
  $name = $_POST['Nombre'];
  $body = $_POST['mensaje']; 

  $host = "xxxxxxx";
  $username = "xxxxxxx";
  $password = "xxxxxxx";

  $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
```

$message=array($_POST[Nombre],$_POST[Evento],$_POST[fecha],$_POST[telefono],$_POST[mensaje]);

```
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
```

This one displays "(Array)" in the body. 
I need some advise or route to follow.

Comment: [This link fix the problem I create the body in the body variable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983673/php-smtp-mail-contact-form?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`$smtp->send` take a string for the `body` argument, not an array (you can see that here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php). You should use PHP `implode` first to create a string from your array and then pass that as the argument e.g.

```
$str = implode("\n", $message);
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $str);
```